# librería RxtxSerial, problemas con 64bits

Tags: java, java-8, java-6

Ante todo un cordial saludo, tengo un problema con un desarrollo que no he realizado yo, el cual
usa la libreria **RxtxSerial**, en **java-6** funciona perfecto, pero al migrar el sistema a **64bits**, no consigo
la librería **RxtxSerial**, para implementarla con **JAVA 8** en 64 bits, o si es recomendable cambiar el,
desarrollo e implementar alguna otra libreria que me permita hacerlo mismo, el sistema usa esta librería,
para poner en funcionamiento un Scaner HoneyWell, aca dejo el codigo que usa y el error.

```
    public void connect() {
    try {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(this.config[0]);
        if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Problema de conexion, puerto ocupado");
        } else {
            CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);

            serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            input = serialPort.getInputStream();
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();
        }
    } catch (NoSuchPortException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problema de conexion, puerto no existe o no hay dispositivo.", ex);
    } catch (PortInUseException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problema de conexion, puerto ocupado.", ex);
    } catch (RuntimeException | IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problema de conexion, error inhabilitante.", ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problema de conexion, error inhabilitante.", ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void disconnect() {
    try {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
        input.close();
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Loggear en log, ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Error en desconexion de Scanner", ex);
        //No se procesa excepcion a proposito, por considerar que un error en disconnect no es inhabilitante para continuar. 

    }
}
```

[image: error al iniciar]

[image: error 2 al iniciar]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola víctor, para 64 bits se pueden descarga de esta pagina los binarios http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java.

Answer (score 1):

A menos que tengas el código fuente de la dll y la recompiles para 64 bits, deberías instalar y usar una JVM de 32 bits (x86).